# Trying to define comments for SPSS in syntax table

Tags: emacs, spss

I'm trying to modify spss.el to provide accurate fontification for SPSS comments. Below is a summary of how SPSS's syntax highlights and treats comments:

`*` = an asterisk starts commment at beginning of line

`\n\n` = two new lines end comments

`.\n` =  period + newline also ends comment

`/*` = slash and star starts comment, and is ended with a single new line
`*/` ends a comment only if on the same line as a /*

So far my syntax table reads:

```
(let ((spss-mode-syntax-table (make-syntax-table)))
  (modify-syntax-entry ?* "<" spss-mode-syntax-table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?. ". 3" spss-mode-syntax-table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?\n "- 34" spss-mode-syntax-table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?' "\"" spss-mode-syntax-table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?\\ "@ " spss-mode-syntax-table)
  spss-mode-syntax-table)
```

This for the most part works, except that the asterisk only functions as a commment delimiter when it's at the beginning of a line. Is there a way to denote that the asterisk is a comment delimiter *only* at the line start?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the /* ... */ part, you can use

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?/ ". 14" st)
(modify-syntax-entry ?* ". 23" st)
(modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">" st)
```

But for the * ... \n\n, you need a different comment style and since it reuses the same chars * and \n as the other comment style, you can't use simple syntax-table settings to explain it to Emacs.  Instead, you'll need to use a `syntax-propertize-function` which will place a `"< b"` syntax on a `*` at beginning of line and a `"> b"` syntax on the `\n` of `\n\n`.  E.g.

```
(set (make-local-variable 'syntax-propertize-function)
     (syntax-propertize-rules
       ("^\\(\\*\\)" (1 "< b"))
       ("\n\\(\n\\)" (1 "> b"))
       ("\\(\\.\\)\n" (1 "> b"))))
```

Comment: Hello, I was reading [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2013-06/msg00146.html) and the respondant (another Stefan?) mentions that it might not work if font-lock is being used. I tried copy-pasting your code snippet to no effect, and then saw that the mode uses font-lock.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, font-lock works just fine with syntax-propertize.  But maybe your Emacs is too old to have syntax-propertize.  Also copy&paste is not enough since you're using different var names and the `set` operation needs to be applied in the right context.